# Regarding regularity of solution of the Heat equation, Brezis' Functional Analysis Theorem 10.1

Tags: sobolev-spaces, proof-explanation, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have started reading Chapter 10 of Brezis' Functional Analysis and run into a problem in the proof of [Theorem 10.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&pg=PA326). I have a question regarding the part where it's shown that $A$ is maximal monotone.(Pages attached below)

[Theorem 10.1 and Theorem 9.25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSv9J.png)

So far I have figured this much. Here $\Omega$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ with $\Gamma = \partial \Omega$ bounded. Take any $f \in L^2(\Omega)$. We have by a previous theorem that $\exists$ a unique weak solution to 
$$u - \Delta u =f \text{ in } \Omega$$ 
$$ u = 0 \text{ on } \Gamma = \partial \Omega $$
That is, $u \in  H_{0}^1(\Omega)$ and
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi + \int_{\Omega}u \phi = \int_{\Omega}f \phi \ \ \ \forall \phi \in H_{0}^1(\Omega)$$
Then by Theorem 9.25, $u \in H^2(\Omega)$ and $\left \| u \right \|_{H^2} \leq C \left \| f \right \|_{L^2}$.

From here on how can we proceed to show that the weak solution $u$ actually turns out to be a classical solution? This has been shown to be true if $u \in C^2(\bar{\Omega})$ as in the image below:
[Classical solution from weak solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaDIF.png)

But I can't see if that applies here or how. I feel like this might be an easy step, but I seem to be stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated

---

[image: Theorem 10.1 and Theorem 9.25]

---

[image: Classical solution from weak solution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weak solution $u$ is not necessarily classical in this case.  Since $f\in L^2$ we conclude that $u \in H^2(\Omega)$.  For $u\in C^2(\bar{\Omega})$ we require that $u-\Delta u \in C(\Omega)$ but without additional a priori estimates on $f$ there is no way to improve regularity on $u$. As Theorem 9.25 states, Sobolev embeddings will ensure that $H^m(\Omega)\subset C(\Omega)$ provided $m$ is sufficiently large.

From the information you provided, in the proof that $A$ is maximal monotone it seems it is only required that $u\in H^2(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega)$ and not $u\in C^2(\bar{\Omega})$.